# Proposal for Security operation center Stack (SOC.SE)

Tags: discussion

You can see the lack of having an SE for Security Operation Center, this is a big deal and can make a big opportunity for a Security specialist to follow their work and share their knowledge and experience under this SE.
I searched for SOC tag and did use @Glorfindel SEDE query searching-the-tags-of-all-stack-exchange but could not find much.
Can I have your opinion about my proposal?

Comment: "this is a big deal" -- why?

Comment: Isn't the fact that there is so little under a SOC tag an indication that there is no support for the idea that it is needed? "Encryption" is the most used tag, "Cryptography" is #8, and we have crypto.SE. "Network" is #6 and there is a networking.SE. "SOC" is on *page* 19...

Comment: @schroeder It is trending in the past 6 months, at least as i see in LinkedIn jobs or etc, but as the link, I shared on Rory Alsop on his answer, it shows you are right.

Answer (score 6):

There are very few aspects of security that only occur in a SOC, which is one reason we do not use a SOC tag much. It really is only needed for a SOC-specific question.

If you search through this site you will see hundreds of questions referring to activities and protocols within SOCs. You don't need to search on a tag.

Your proposal will needlessly fragment the site. The information security industry does not fragment like that. So not only is it not a big deal, it literally is not an issue here.

Comment: There is just 25 question with soc tag but the total amount of question on SecuritySE are 59,130, it is less than 1%, part of your answer makes sense but just search some SOC terms and see how many of them refers to SecuritySE?

Comment: Can you explain what it is you are intending. You realise most things SOC teams do don't require categorising as SOC, right? We have things like intrusion analysis, scenario simulations, red team detection etc etc etc - none of which need a SOC tag.

Comment: The results of a search engine about SOC terms and topics in general or in particular or a specific issue rarely refers to SecuritySE, how come the largest Q&A website in it Security has this share of search engine?

Comment: i did a comparison on google trend [https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?cat=5&date=today%205-y&q=Security%20operations%20center,cyber%20security,cryptography,Encryption,TLS] and result agrees with what you mention.

Comment: It was not just about tag it was about content.